# Wheel of robot URDF resets steering angle when it "rolls"

Tags: ros

I am currently trying to create a basic URDF model of our robot (which is basically a modified mobility scooter with front steering + rear-wheel-drive, like a car) for usage in ROS / Gazebo.

I managed to get steering working ("turning the wheel left or right along the Z axis, until a threshold is triggered"). Now I assume that I also need to give all the wheels it's ability to drive/roll forward and backward, using a joint with type "continuous".

Unfortuantely, this is where I'm stuck right now. **Everytime I steer, and then try to change the "roll" parameter, the steering position resets to zero.** You can check this out in this simulator: http://www.mymodelrobot.appspot.com (the URDF code needs to be put on the right side and then you click on "Load robot URDF", then you can change the parameters on the top right side). I only tried it out on one wheel (left front or "links front" in the URDF - I am writing the names in German sometimes).

I really don't know what's the problem, I tried several modifications. Do you know what the problem here could be?

Here's the URDF:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot name="ben">

  <!-- * * * Link Definitions * * * -->

  <link name="basis_unten">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0.35" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="1.70 0.66 0.50"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="Cyan1">
                <color rgba="0.0 0.9 0.9 0.9"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
        <collision>
            <geometry>
            <box size="2.70 0.88 0.50"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>

    <link name="basis_oben">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="-0.1 0 0.84" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="1.50 0.66 0.68"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="Cyan1">
                <color rgba="0.0 0.9 0.9 0.9"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
            <box size="2.50 0.88 0.68"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>    
    </link>

   <link name="reifen_front_links">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.57075 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.10" radius="0.155"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="reifenfarbe">
                <color rgba="0 0 0 1.0"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

    <link name="reifen_front_rechts">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.57075 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.10" radius="0.155"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="reifenfarbe">
                <color rgba="0 0 0 1.0"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

    <link name="reifen_back_links">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="-0.6 0.29 0.155" rpy="1.57075 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.10" radius="0.155"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="reifenfarbe">
                <color rgba="0 0 0 1.0"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

    <link name="reifen_back_rechts">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="-0.6 -0.29 0.155" rpy="1.57075 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.10" radius="0.155"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="reifenfarbe">
                <color rgba="0 0 0 1.0"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

    <link name="lidar">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length ="0.041" radius="0.03625"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="lidarfarbe">
        <color rgba="0.1 0 0 1"/>

      </material>
      <origin rpy="0 0.785 0" xyz="0.8 0 1.16"/>
    </visual>
  </link>

<link name="kamera_vorne">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.02 0.15 0.03"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="kamerafarbe">
        <color rgba="0 0 1 1"/>
      </material>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.77 0 1.01"/>
    </visual>
  </link>

<link name="kamera_links">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0.50 0.29 1.05" rpy="1.57075 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.10" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="kamerafarbe">
                <color rgba="0 0 1 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="kamera_rechts">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0.50 -0.29 1.05" rpy="-1.57075 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.10" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="kamerafarbe">
                <color rgba="0 0 1 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="kamera_back">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="-0.85 0 1.11" rpy="0 -1.57 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.04" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="kamerafarbe">
                <color rgba="0 0 1 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

    <link name="ultrasonic_front_links">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0.75 0.29 0.5" rpy="1.57075 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.10" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="ultrasonic_front_rechts">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0.75 -0.29 0.5" rpy="-1.57075 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.10" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

    <link name="ultrasonic_back_links">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="-0.75 0.29 0.5" rpy="1.57075 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.10" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

    <link name="ultrasonic_back_rechts">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="-0.75 -0.29 0.5" rpy="-1.57075 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.10" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="ultrasonic_fresseobenl">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0.85 0.045 0.77" rpy="0 1.57 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.02" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="ultrasonic_fresseobenr">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0.85 -0.045 0.77" rpy="0 1.57 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.02" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>


<link name="ultrasonic_fresseuntenl">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0.85 0.23 0.42" rpy="0 1.57 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.02" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="ultrasonic_fresseuntenr">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0.85 -0.23 0.42" rpy="0 1.57 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.02" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>




<link name="ultrasonic_rueckenoben">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="-0.85 0 0.77" rpy="0 -1.57 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.02" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>



<link name="ultrasonic_rueckenuntenl">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="-0.85 0.27 0.42" rpy="0 -1.57 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.02" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="ultrasonic_rueckenuntenm">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="-0.85 0 0.42" rpy="0 -1.57 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.02" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="ultrasonic_rueckenuntenr">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="-0.85 -0.27 0.42" rpy="0 -1.57 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.02" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<joint name="reifenlinks_joint" type="revolute">
        <parent link="basis_unten"/>
        <child link="reifen_front_links"/>
        <origin xyz="0.46 0.29 0.155" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <limit lower="-0.35" upper="0.35" effort="10" velocity="3"/>
    </joint>

<joint name="reifenrechts_joint" type="revolute">
        <parent link="basis_unten"/>
        <child link="reifen_front_rechts"/>
        <origin xyz="0.46 -0.29 0.155" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <limit lower="-0.35" upper="0.35" effort="10" velocity="3"/>
    </joint>

<link name="right_front_steering">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size ="0.01 0.01 0.01"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    </visual>
  </link>

  <joint name="right_front_steering_to_right_front_wheel" type="continuous">
    <parent link="right_front_steering"/>
    <child link="reifen_front_links"/>
    <origin xyz="0.46 0.29 0.155"/>
    <axis   xyz="0 1 0"/>
  </joint>
</robot>
```

Comment: Did you try to change the type of wheel from `continuous` to `rotary`?

Comment: Thank you @Benyamin - I already solved it, it was pretty messed up and then I just decided to rebuild it. Now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completely rebuilt the URDF file from scratch as it was pretty messed up (stumbled apon other problems) and now it works.

Here's the new URDF for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot name="ben">

<!-- * * * Link Definitions * * * -->

  <!-- * * * Basis * * * -->

<link name="basis_unten">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0.35" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="1.70 0.66 0.50"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="Cyan1">
                <color rgba="0.0 0.9 0.9 0.9"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
        <collision>
            <geometry>
            <box size="2.50 0.96 0.50"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
</link>

<link name="basis_oben">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <box size="1.50 0.66 0.68"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="Cyan1">
                <color rgba="0.0 0.9 0.9 0.9"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
            <box size="2.50 0.96 0.68"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>    
    </link>

    <!-- * * * Reifen * * * -->

<link name="reifen_front_links">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.57075 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.10" radius="0.155"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="reifenfarbe">
                <color rgba="0 0 0 1.0"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
</link>

<link name="reifen_front_rechts">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="1.57075 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.10" radius="0.155"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="reifenfarbe">
                <color rgba="0 0 0 1.0"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
</link>

<link name="reifen_back_links">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.10" radius="0.155"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="reifenfarbe">
                <color rgba="0 0 0 1.0"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="reifen_back_rechts">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.10" radius="0.155"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="reifenfarbe">
                <color rgba="0 0 0 1.0"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

    <!-- * * * Sensorik * * * -->

<link name="lidar">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length ="0.041" radius="0.03625"/>
      </geometry>
      <material name="lidarfarbe">
        <color rgba="0.1 0 0 1"/>
      </material>
    </visual>
  </link>

<link name="zed_left_camera">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 1.57 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.007" length=".031"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="dark_grey">
                <color rgba="0.1 0.1 0.1 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
    </link>
<link name="zed_center">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0.02 0.15 0.03"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="kamerafarbe">
                <color rgba="0 0 1 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
    </link>
<link name="zed_right_camera">
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 1.57 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder radius="0.007" length=".031"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="dark_grey">
                <color rgba="0.1 0.1 0.1 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
</link>
<link name="zed_depth_camera" />

<link name="kamera_links">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.10" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="kamerafarbe">
                <color rgba="0 0 1 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="kamera_rechts">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.10" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="kamerafarbe">
                <color rgba="0 0 1 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="kamera_back">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.04" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="kamerafarbe">
                <color rgba="0 0 1 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="ultrasonic_front_links">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.10" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="ultrasonic_front_rechts">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.10" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="ultrasonic_back_links">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.10" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="ultrasonic_back_rechts">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.10" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="ultrasonic_gesichtobenl">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.02" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="ultrasonic_gesichtobenr">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.02" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="ultrasonic_gesichtuntenl">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.02" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="ultrasonic_gesichtuntenr">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.02" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="ultrasonic_rueckenoben">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.02" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="ultrasonic_rueckenuntenl">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.02" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="ultrasonic_rueckenuntenm">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.02" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
    </link>

<link name="ultrasonic_rueckenuntenr">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length ="0.02" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="sensorfarbe">
                <color rgba="1 0 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>   
</link>


<!-- * * * JOINT DEFINITIONS * * * -->

    <!-- * * * Basis * * * -->

<joint name="basis_zu_basis_oben" type="fixed">
     <origin xyz="-0.1 0 0.84" rpy="0 0 0"/>
     <parent link="basis_unten"/>
     <child link="basis_oben"/>
</joint>

    <!-- * * * Reifen Links * * * -->

<joint name="basis_zu_links_front_steering" type="revolute">
        <parent link="basis_unten"/>
        <child link="links_front_steering"/>
        <origin xyz="0.46 0.29 0.155" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <limit lower="-0.35" upper="0.35" effort="10" velocity="3"/>
</joint>

<link name="links_front_steering">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size =".001 .001 .001"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    </visual>
</link>

<joint name="links_front_steering_to_reifen_front_links" type="continuous">
    <parent link="links_front_steering"/>
    <child link="reifen_front_links"/>
    <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
    <axis   xyz="0 1 0"/>
</joint>

    <!-- * * * Reifen Rechts * * * -->


<joint name="basis_zu_rechts_front_steering" type="revolute">
    <parent link="basis_unten"/>
    <child link="rechts_front_steering"/>
    <origin xyz="0.46 -0.29 0.155" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
    <limit lower="-0.35" upper="0.35" effort="10" velocity="3"/>
</joint>

<link name="rechts_front_steering">
    <visual>
      <geometry>
        <box size =".001 .001 .001"/>
      </geometry>
      <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
    </visual>
</link>

<joint name="rechts_front_steering_to_reifen_front_rechts" type="continuous">
    <parent link="rechts_front_steering"/>
    <child link="reifen_front_rechts"/>
    <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0"/>
    <axis   xyz="0 1 0"/>
</joint>

  <!-- * * * Reifen hinten * * * -->

<joint name="basis_zu_reifen_back_links" type="continuous">
    <parent link="basis_unten"/>
    <child link="reifen_back_links"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.6 0.29 0.155" rpy="1.57075 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
</joint>

<joint name="basis_zu_reifen_back_rechts" type="continuous">
    <parent link="basis_unten"/>
    <child link="reifen_back_rechts"/>
   <origin xyz="-0.6 -0.29 0.155" rpy="1.57075 0 0"/>
    <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
</joint>

  <!-- * * * Sensorik * * * -->

<joint name="basis_zu_lidar" type="fixed">
     <parent link="basis_unten"/>
     <child link="lidar"/>
     <origin rpy="0 0.75 0" xyz="0.75 0 1.15"/>
</joint>

<joint name="basis_zu_zed_center" type="fixed">
    <parent link="basis_unten"/>
    <child link="zed_center"/>
    <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.77 0 1.01"/>
</joint>

<joint name="zed_left_camera_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="zed_center"/>
        <child link="zed_left_camera"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0.06 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
</joint>

<joint name="zed_depth_camera_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="zed_left_camera"/>
        <child link="zed_depth_camera"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="-1.5707963267948966 0 -1.5707963267948966" />
</joint>

<joint name="zed_right_camera_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="zed_center"/>
        <child link="zed_right_camera"/>
        <origin xyz="0 -0.06 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
</joint>

<joint name="basis_zu_kamera_links" type="fixed">
    <parent link="basis_unten"/>
    <child link="kamera_links"/>
    <origin xyz="0.50 0.29 1.05" rpy="1.57075 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="basis_zu_kamera_rechts" type="fixed">
    <parent link="basis_unten"/>
    <child link="kamera_rechts"/>
    <origin xyz="0.50 -0.29 1.05" rpy="-1.57075 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="basis_zu_kamera_back" type="fixed">
    <parent link="basis_unten"/>
    <child link="kamera_back"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.85 0 1.11" rpy="0 -1.57 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="basis_zu_ultrasonic_front_links" type="fixed">
    <parent link="basis_unten"/>
    <child link="ultrasonic_front_links"/>
    <origin xyz="0.75 0.29 0.5" rpy="1.57075 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="basis_zu_ultrasonic_front_rechts" type="fixed">
    <parent link="basis_unten"/>
    <child link="ultrasonic_front_rechts"/>
    <origin xyz="0.75 -0.29 0.5" rpy="-1.57075 0 0"/>

</joint>

<joint name="basis_zu_ultrasonic_back_links" type="fixed">
    <parent link="basis_unten"/>
    <child link="ultrasonic_back_links"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.75 0.29 0.5" rpy="1.57075 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="basis_zu_ultrasonic_back_rechts" type="fixed">
    <parent link="basis_unten"/>
    <child link="ultrasonic_back_rechts"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.75 -0.29 0.5" rpy="-1.57075 0 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="basis_zu_ultrasonic_gesichtobenl" type="fixed">
    <parent link="basis_unten"/>
    <child link="ultrasonic_gesichtobenl"/>
    <origin xyz="0.85 0.045 0.77" rpy="1.57 1.82 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="basis_zu_ultrasonic_gesichtobenr" type="fixed">
    <parent link="basis_unten"/>
    <child link="ultrasonic_gesichtobenr"/>
    <origin xyz="0.85 -0.045 0.77" rpy="1.57 1.32 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="basis_zu_ultrasonic_gesichtuntenl" type="fixed">
    <parent link="basis_unten"/>
    <child link="ultrasonic_gesichtuntenl"/>
    <origin xyz="0.85 0.23 0.42" rpy="1.57 1.80 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="basis_zu_ultrasonic_gesichtuntenr" type="fixed">
    <parent link="basis_unten"/>
    <child link="ultrasonic_gesichtuntenr"/>
    <origin xyz="0.85 -0.23 0.42" rpy="1.57 1.34 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="basis_zu_ultrasonic_rueckenoben" type="fixed">
    <parent link="basis_unten"/>
    <child link="ultrasonic_rueckenoben"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.85 0 0.77" rpy="0 -1.57 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="basis_zu_ultrasonic_rueckenuntenl" type="fixed">
    <parent link="basis_unten"/>
    <child link="ultrasonic_rueckenuntenl"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.85 0.27 0.42" rpy="0 -1.57 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="basis_zu_ultrasonic_rueckenuntenm" type="fixed">
    <parent link="basis_unten"/>
    <child link="ultrasonic_rueckenuntenm"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.85 0 0.42" rpy="0 -1.57 0"/>
</joint>

<joint name="basis_zu_ultrasonic_rueckenuntenr" type="fixed">
    <parent link="basis_unten"/>
    <child link="ultrasonic_rueckenuntenr"/>
    <origin xyz="-0.85 -0.27 0.42" rpy="0 -1.57 0"/>
</joint>
</robot>
```